# how to take a few word into mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

i have a table like this

```
+----+--------------+------------------+
| id | product_name |   description    |
+----+--------------+------------------+
|  1 | Orange 200g  | Sale Orange 200g |
|  2 | Grape 300g   | Sale Grape 300g  |
|  3 | Apple 400g   | Sale Apple 400g  |
+----+--------------+------------------+
```

i want to add a word in the description with remove the `200g` so it can be like this

```
+----+--------------+-------------------------------+
| id | product_name |          description          |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | Orange 200g  | Sale Orange 200g, Sale Orange |
|  2 | Grape 300g   | Sale Grape 300g, Sale Grape   |
|  3 | Apple 400g   | Sale Apple 400g, Sale Apple   |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------+
```

I've tried with this query

```
UPDATE myTable SET description = 
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', description, REPLACE(how to replace it))
```

Comment: could you give me suggestion what should i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here:

```sql
UPDATE myTable
SET description = CONCAT(description, ', ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, ' ', 2));
```

### Demo